# Need Help to solve ajax issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I create safari extension and i inject js in this extension. In this JS code i send ajax call which create following error in console. "Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers"
here is my code:

this function i copied from net to solve cross domain issue but its not working please help me to figure out this.

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        // XHR has 'withCredentials' property only if it supports CORS
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") { // if IE use XDR
      xhr = new XDomainRequest();
      xhr.open(method, url);
   } else {
       xhr = null;
   }
   return xhr;
}


var request = createCORSRequest("get", "https://www.karmora.com/list.xml");

if (request) {
   // Define a callback function
   request.onload = function () {
};
   // Send request
   request.send();
}

$.get('https://example.com', function (data) {
    alert("Ajax call successfull");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related with [Same-origin_policy](http://ttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

If you have access to the server, add to Apache Web Server virtual host configuration the following settings:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
```

Comment: I used same code in chrome extension its working fine. error just in safari browser.